# Definite article-is it necessary?

Tags: articles

Is this sentence correct with or without "the"? Why?

> You tidy the living room while I do the washing-up. That’ll be ***the*** quickest.

Comment: I'd say both are fine. the is the "most correct", but many do drop it.

Comment: I would use *the*, because technically you are saying "That’ll be the quickest (way)" where the noun *way* gets the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either, but the meaning is slightly different in theory (though I can't detect any difference in practice).

If you say *That'll be the quickest*, there is an implied "way". "Quickest" is an adjective. (You cannot omit the noun like this with most adjectives, but there is an exception for superlatives)

If you say *That'll be quickest*, I would interpret "quickest" as an adverb, and there is nothing omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about the *singular*

> **quickest**

way to get the chores done, out of the different permutations

> **the**

is best to use.

> **the** fastest
>   **the** best
>   **the** easiest